# Can anyone know about store procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables,

Table A contains the following fields

```
ID                   
docu_id              
doc
```

and table B

```
docu_id
Category
Type
format
filename
```

I want to make a store procedure to insert data to two tables.

Comment: Hi @jomachi, there is hundreds of tutorials on the web for this. You have to show that you at least attempted to solve this problem on your own. No one on these forums will do the work for you. Show at least some code examples of what you have tried and I'm sure everyone will be more than willing to help. A question like this will recieve alot of down votes.

Comment: Yes I know that my friend, I searched a lot but I did not found any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure
     @docu_id INT,
     @Category VARCHAR(50),
     @Type VARCHAR(50),
     @Format VARCHAR(50),
     @FileName VARCHAR(255),
     @doc VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO B
     (
         Category,
         Type,
         Format,
         FileName
     )
     VALUES
     (
        @Category,
        @Type,
        @Format,
        @FileName
     )

    INSERT INTO A
    (
        docu_id,
        doc
    )
    VALUES
    (
        SCOPE_IDENTITY(),
        @doc
    )
END 
GO
```

Comment: Yes docu_id is a foreign key. Thank you my friend I'll try it.

Comment: It gives me error in (DECLARE InsertedId AS INT). It says expecting CURSOR or ID